# Combining two uint32 to ulong64 in c++

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I am looking into how to convert two uint32 values to a ulong64 value.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want the result of converting them to be? Sum, difference, product, alternate bits?

Answer (score 3):

as Mysticial suggests, use a shift.

```
uint32 a = 0xff00ff00;
uint32 b = 0x00ff00ff;

ulong64 c = ((ulong64)a) << 32 | b; // 0xff00ff0000ff00ff
```

Comment: Just don't forget the conversion before the shift.

Comment: It's a little prettier if you do `ulong64 c = a << 32ull | b;`.

Comment: To extract back UINT32 values, do I need to do an XOR?

Comment: To get the high uint32, `uint32 a = (uint32)(c >> 32)`.  To get the low uint32, `uint32 b = (uint32)(c & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFULL)`.

Comment: All this *and please* put these things into well-named functions.